# Maximum Minimum in Array in C (with pointers)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a problem, when I run it, the minimum and maximum don't appear properly.
Any suggestions?
I have to make the range appear.
I tried it with pointers.
The Exercises could be done otherwise for sure but I want to understand my mistakes with this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "simpio.h"
#include "genlib.h"

int readArray(int array[100]);

main()
{
  int array[100], i, size, *min, *max;

  printf("Enter the elements of the array, one per line.\n");
  printf("Use -1 to signal the end of the list.\n");

  readArray(array);

  min = array;
  *min = *array;

  for (i=1; i<size; i++)
  {
    if ( *(array+i) < *min )
    {
      *min = *(array+i);
    }
  }
  max = array;
  *max = *array;

  for (i=1; i<size; i++)
  {
    if ( *(array+i) > *max )
    {
      *max = *(array+i);
    }
  }

  printf("The range of values is %d-%d \n", *min, *max);

  system("pause");
}

int readArray(int array[100])
{
  int i, size;
  size = 0;

  for (i=0; i<100; i++)
  {
    printf("? ");
    array[i] = GetInteger();
    size += 1;
    if (array[i] == -1) {break;}
  }
  for(i=0; i<size-1; i++)
  {
    printf("%d ", array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Note that `*(array + i)` is the same as, and should be written as, `array[i]`. When you set `min=array`, you're using `array[0]` to store the minimum value. Then when you set `max=array`, you're using `array[0]` as the maximum. That's why the code doesn't work.

Comment: You can also use the same loop for both, the minimum and the maximum.

Comment: PLEASE DON'T write code like `if (array[i] == -1) {break;}` ...

Comment: @M.M Because it's bad taste and it makes me want to delete wherever I see it.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the value at `*min` which is the first value in the array. What you want is to make a pointer to the value, hence what you really need is

```
min = array;
```

and

```
min = array + i;
```

or `min = &array[i]`.

The `*` operator dereferences the pointer, you don't want to do that until you print it. You can use the `min` and `max` pointers to point anywhere in the array, you can make the `const` for example to prevent accidentally writing to the spot they are pointing to at a given time.

Here is an example built from your own code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int readArray(int *array, int size);

int
main(void)
{
    int array[100], i, *min, *max;

    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Enter the elements of the array, one per line.\n");
    printf("Use -1 to signal the end of the list.\n");

    readArray(array, 100);

    min = array;
    max = array;
    for (i = 1; i < 100 ; i++) {
        if (*(array + i) < *min)
            min = array + i;
        if (*(array + i) > *max)
            max = array + i;
    }
    printf("The range of values is %d-%d \n", *min, *max);
}

int 
readArray(int *array, int size)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        array[i] = 1 + rand() % 100;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```